# Annuity immediate and present value

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

> A borrower has has the following options for repaying a loan:
>
> 1. sixty monthly payments of $100$ at the end of each month
> 2. A single payment of $6000$ at month $k$
>
> Interest is a nominal rate of $.12$ per month meaning $i=.12/12=.01$.
>
> Find $k$.

I know the first part is an annuity immediate with $$100 \frac{1-(1.01)^{-60}}{.01}=4495.504.$$

Now we want to find when $6000$ of payment will be equal to the $60$ monthly payments of $100$ which tells me want to know when will the accumulation of $6000$ at $.12%$ will be equal. Since we are working with present value $k$ will be negative

$$4495.504=6000(1.01)^{-k} \to 28.9.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the assumption is that $k$ is chosen in such a way that both options result in the same present value, then the equation to be solved is $$6000 v^k = 100 a_{\overline{60}\rceil j} = 100 \frac{1 - v^{60}}{j},$$ where $j = 0.01$ is the monthly effective rate of interest and $v = 1/(1+j)$ is the monthly present value discount factor.  Therefore, $$k = \frac{\log (1 - v^{60}) - \log 60 j}{\log v} \approx 29.012273332\ldots.$$  Your answer is off slightly, for reasons I cannot determine.

If rounded to the nearest integer, this corresponds to a single lump sum payment at the end of $29$ months, with present value $$6000 v^{29} \approx 4496.05,$$ whereas the annuity has present value $4495.50$, for a difference of approximately $0.55$.  Consequently, the payment of $6000$ is a slight overpayment compared to the annuity:  to get the same present value, this lump sum can be adjusted downward to $5999.2673\ldots$.